# How to work around a Windows ListView issue?

Tags: winforms, listview, controls

If the listview (in Details mode) is scrolled down and then you resize the listview, and if you resize columns in the Resize event or even Layout event, the contents get corrupted badly.

To reproduce, make a new C# project and put this code in there:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView lv = new ListView();
        lv.Size = ClientSize;
        lv.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
        lv.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
        lv.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
        lv.View = View.Details;
        lv.FullRowSelect = true;
        lv.Resize += lv_Resize;
        Controls.Add(lv);

        string[] s = new string[2];
        s[0] = "hrd";
        s[1] = "igwegmg";        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(s));
        }

        lv_Resize(lv, null);
    }

    private void lv_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
        lv.Columns[1].Width = lv.ClientSize.Width - lv.Columns[0].Width;
    }
```

Run it, scroll the list down a bit, resize the form to show all items by dragging the bottom of the form downwards.

Resize it smaller to where the scroll bar shows up, then it gets worse.
Or instead of resizing just maximize and restore the form.

Notice also there's a bunch (depending on how much you scrolled) of empty items at the top of the listview, you cant click on them. To restore it to normal you have to do one of two things.

1. Repopulate the items (not good - I have too many items and I lose my scroll position).
2. manually if you resize the form to where the scrollbar pops up, then you scroll the scroll bar to the bottom, then move your mouse off the scroll bar, and then back on top of the scrollbar you will see the scrollbar resize itself, at which point you can drag the scrollbar to the top, and then its back to normal.

If you `RedrawItems`, then at least you can see all the items again, but you still get the blank items at the top. Doing a `begininvoke` to a function that calls `RedrawItems` after a resize/layout event doesn't always work.

Any ideas on this bug? I really don't want to use any other controls or third party software.

Comment: You say "contents get corrupted badly".  Define.  Bad data, visual artifacting?

Comment: visual artifacts. text disappears and halfway reappears and empty rows above real rows.

Comment: Are you drawing these items yourself?  It sounds like a simple refresh issue.

Comment: Not drawing them myself. Basic Listview usage as far as I know. The code I posted is everything you need to reproduce it.

Comment: There might be a more proper way to resize the columns? That's the portion that causes the behavior. I have tried setting column width to -2 and tried using listview in VirtualMode with no change

Comment: I wonder if a screenshot might help pique people's interest? If people need to create a project and run code to know what you are talking about, you may struggle to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed other ListView's in my app not exhibiting the bug. Found out its because they were resizing columns inside the Form's Resize event.

Workaround: Dont Resize columns in the ListView.Resize() but do it in the Form.Resize() event.

I'll leave this open a littelwhile incase some of you already been researching for a workaround to use ListView.Resize()